# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf6' in position 134: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, email, utf-8, encode

I'm trying to create a python program which includes sending an email and I'm getting the UnicodeEncodeError error. None of the solutions I've seen with this error work in my script. I tried to add `receiver = str(u' '.join(receiver).encode('utf-8'))` in the for loop but it doesn't work as well. Here's a part of my code (if you want I can post the whole code):

```
werewolfs = []

def group_roles(group):
    for i in range(4):
        werewolfs.append(group[i])


group_roles(group1)
group_roles(group2)
group_roles(group3)

for receiver in werewolfs:
    receiver = str(u' '.join(receiver).encode('utf-8'))
    DATA = 'From:%s\nTo:%s\nSubject:%s\n\n%s' % (my_email, receiver, subject, werewolf_mail)
    server.sendmail(my_email, receiver, DATA)
```

This is the whole error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dominikb/.config/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.3/scratches/werewolf.py", line 131, in <module>
    server.sendmail(my_email, receiver, DATA)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 859, in sendmail
    msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf6' in position 134: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Does someone know the solution to this? That would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem that `str()` tries to encode unicode characters (\xf6) using a default character encoder. To solve your issue, you can remove `str()` and just use `.encode()`.

```
receiver = u' '.join(receiver).encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this also doesn't work and it gives me the same error.

Comment: Ah, mistake. The error is generated while sending the email. You could try to send the email via server.sendmail(my_email, receiver.encode('utf-8'), DATA.encode('utf-8')

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue! I figured out that it didn't work because I had German letters like ä, ö, ü, and ß in the message I wrote. I removed them and it worked. Is there still a way to write an email in python with such letters?